# How to get cost reports for prefixes in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

I have tagged unversioned data stored in AWS S3 in the following form:

```
<bucket>/foo/
             item-1
             item-2
             item-3 (inserted, read, then deleted)
        /bar/
             item-4
             item-5
```

There is one bucket, several prefixes like `foo` and `bar`, and many items using those prefixes. Items are inserted, read, updated, and deleted daily. I would like to get a cost breakdown in S3, using prefixes, for example

```
+--------------+---------+---------------+
|     Date     | Cost, $ | AWS S3 Prefix |
+--------------+---------+---------------+
| 25-Jan-2024  |      11 | <bucket>/foo/*|
| 25-Jan-2024  |      15 | <bucket>/bar/*|
+--------------+---------+---------------+
```

I've looked at using [Cost Allocation tags](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce/client/get_cost_and_usage_with_resources.html) but that seems to be limited to a bucket level. I cannot get the cost breakdown based on differently-tagged resources inside the bucket. The [CUR reports](https://awstip.com/insights-from-aws-cost-and-usage-reports-a0e15a1ee152) also don't group S3 resources using prefixes. Both cost allocation tags and CUR allow me to get this data:

```
+--------------+---------+---------------+
|     Date     | Cost, $ | AWS S3 Prefix |
+--------------+---------+---------------+
| 25-Jan-2024  |      11 | <bucket>      |
+--------------+---------+---------------+
```

How do I programmatically get the costs of resources in AWS S3 grouped by a prefix?

Comment: you cannot get from CE but you can calculate yourself using s3 inventory reports

Comment: And there are third party tools, like [this one](https://github.com/seligman/dir_sizer) that will calculate storage costs for you on a prefix basis.

Comment: Neither S3 inventory report nor the storage calculator provide the answer. These tools will not include data inserted-read-deleted between the report runs; or data that is read many-many times. There are also additional costs like data encryption and KMS usage. While the tools will give an approximation based on the data size and object count, it's not the actual billed costs by AWS. And I would like to get the actual billed cost per prefix in the bucket. I know the costs will be provided if I use 1 bucket for 1 prefix. But there is a hard limit of 1000 buckets per account.

Comment: Understood.  Short of tracking the information yourself with S3 activity logging, there is no real answer to get per-prefix cost data.